# FactoryGirl & Mongoid embedded_in and build_list

Tags: rspec, mongoid, factory-bot

### The Issue

Okay so the issue I am having is with FactoryGirl building embedded assignments in my Quiz which uses mongo instead of active record.  I tried using a build_list which works with my active record models, but I am having an issue with doing this with mongoid...

I am able to call the following and get quiz_assignments back:

```
@quiznos.quiz_assignments.new(due_at: Time.now+ 1.day, published_at: Time.now)
```

However if I call

```
@quiznos = FactoryGirl.build(:quizWassignments)
```

@quiznos will have a created quiz, but @quiz.quiz_assignments == []

I can even run the following and have past

```
@quiz = FactoryGirl.build(:quiz)
@quiznos = FactoryGirl.build(:quiz_assignment, quiz: @quiz)
@quiz.quiz_assignments.should == [@quiznos]
```

### The Question

Is there a way to get this to work with :quizWassignments?

### The Code

```
class Quiz
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  field :user_id
  field :title
  field :description
  field :assignment_id
  field :due_at, :type => DateTime
  field :published_at, :type => DateTime
  embeds_many :quiz_assignments
end

class QuizAssignment
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps 
  field :due_at, :type => DateTime
  field :published_at, :type => DateTime
  embedded_in :quiz
  embeds_many :quiz_assignees
  validates_presence_of :due_at, :published_at
  validates_associated :quiz_assignees
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :quiz do
    title { Factory.next(:name) }
    description { Factory.next(:description) }
    quiz_type "Practice"

    factory :quizWassignments do
      ignore do
        count 3
      end
      after_create do |quiz, evaluator|
        FactoryGirl.build_list(:quiz_assignment, evaluator.count, quiz: quiz)
      end
    end
  end

  factory :quiz_assignment do
    due_at Time.now + 1.day
    published_at Time.now
  end
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I first switched from Active Record to Mongoid, I had a lot of trouble getting Factory Girl to play nice. I ended up switching to [Fabrication](http://fabricationgem.org/) - which supports Mongoid out of the box.

Comment: theTRON i will try out Fabrication thanks for the tip.  I did seem to find a work around by defining the association but wasn't able to create the has_many like usual.  I had to do    

factory :quizWassignments do
      quiz_assignments { [Factory.build(:quiz_assignment)] }
end

However after checking out Fabrication's documentation, I am already installing it getting ready to try it out!  It looks awesome.

Comment: Mannnnn!!!... It's so much easier with Fabricator. The only thing that I like over FG right now is defining factories within factories instead of using the :from => hook.  But that's about it!  Let me show you the difference in the code that I found for creating embedded_many objects.  https://gist.github.com/2583902

Comment: @theTRON, I have emails embedded in person object using polymorphic association.  I'm doing similar to what you have in your gist but getting "BSON::InvalidDocument: Cannot serialize an object of class Mongoid::Relations::Embedded::Many into BSON.".  Please see here https://gist.github.com/3017471 for the code. Any help is greatly appreciated